# Plotly: changing axis range in surface subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following minimal reproducible example and can't find how to change the z-axis range for the subplots

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

main_fig = make_subplots(
rows= 4, 
cols= 4,
specs = [[{'type': 'surface'} for k in range(4)] for j in range(4)],
horizontal_spacing = 0.05,
vertical_spacing=0.05)

axis = np.arange(50)
for k, spec in enumerate(range(16)):
    fig = go.Surface(x=axis, y=axis, z=axis[:,None] * axis[None,:], showscale=False)
    main_fig.append_trace(fig, row = k//4 + 1, col = k%4 + 1)

main_fig.update_traces(showlegend=False)
main_fig.update_layout(height=800, width=800)
```

I tried with variations of `fig.update_layout` inside the loop, so far without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the 3D axes, adjust the xyz axis in the section called scene, respectively. Please refer to the reference for [examples](https://plotly.com/python/3d-axes/#range-of-axes). I set all z-axes manually, but I am sure there are more efficient codes.

```
main_fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene1=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene2=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene3=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene4=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene5=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene6=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene7=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene8=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene9=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene10=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene11=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene12=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene13=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene14=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene15=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000])),
    scene16=dict(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000]))
)
```

[image]

Comment: your daily visit to plotly forum is too short.

Comment: @xecafe How does my answer relate to staying in the community? What is the truth of your comment?

Answer (score 1):

The short solution to set some attributes of each scene is as follows:

```
main_fig.update_scenes(zaxis=dict(nticks=4, range=[0,1000]))
```

Now `print(main_fig.layout)` to inspect the scenes new settings.